# How to achieve translucent pomegranate material?

Tags: materials, node-editor, transparency

### Wanting to model a pomegranate kernel, I modelled two objects

- The outer shell (red outer watery covering)
- The seed (inner opaque whitish seed)

  [image: two objects with parent child relation, pomegranate kernel]
  [image: in material preview mode]

### The seed

[image: current node settings for the seed]

I want this to be opaque, but I don't want it's edge to have 100% opacity. I want it to blend with the outer shell more.

### The outer shell

[image: to left of base color is a color ramp node, not in relation with it, different color gradient for a lot of such kernels]

I played with IOR, transmission, alpha, subsurface scattering, roughness and specular.
I reached a point where I know what all these terms mean but I still am very indecisive to move forward. I feel there is something that I am doing wrong. 
[image: few renders with different settings]

### Desired result

[image: some pomegranate kernels with the look I want to achieve]

### Conclusion

I looked at various transparency node settings, tried using them but I am still not getting the fundamentals of nodes. How to use a particular node, how to decide which one to use over the other and how to cascade two or more nodes.

I am relatively new to CG, there are a lot of things that I am not aware of, nodes being one of them. Any sort of help or introduction to new concepts or link to articles/videos is welcomed.

Comment: Principled BSDF is a good all-in-one solution that covers most basic cases, but some times it is insufficient and you get better results and more fine grain control by by manually combining other nodes with a *Mix Shader* and some gradients

Comment: Which renderer are you planning to use? It looks as if Cycles volumetrics might have a place here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's think like a photographer.

[image]

1. Proper lighting is essential - white background, strong backlight, fitting HDRi
2. Shader - Principled BSDF will do (let's keep it simple)
3. Use post-processing - adjusting midtone contrast, color-corrections

[image]

Outer Seed shader:

- Roughness - pretty low, it needs to reflect environment and not
  obstruct transmission
- Clearcoat - just an artistic choice, as the outer seed has a thin glossy skin
- Transmission - full 1
- IOR - 1.6
- Trans. rougness - 0,1 to distort the light a bit more

---

*Notes:*
When going for proper realism you'd use Volumetrics, Subsurface scattering and some textures for a more organic look.

But all things considered, proper lighting is everything here :).